# ¿Cómo crear espacio a la derecha en Highcharts? (spacingRight no functiona)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Estoy intentando crear un poco de espacio a la derecha de la gráfica para que la gráfica permita ver bien los números de la axis de la derecha.

[image]

```
chart:{
    spacingRight: 100, // no funciona
    ...
}
```

Intenté utilizar ese código, pero no me funciona, la gráfica sigue saliendo como en la imagen arriba.

Aquí adjunto código entero:

```
$(function() {
  $('#testing').highcharts('StockChart', {

    navigator: {
      enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      allButtonsEnabled: false,
      selected: 0,
      inputEnabled: false,
    },

    series: [{
      name: "...",

      chart:{
          spacingRight: 10, // ESTO NO FUNCTIONA
          margin:0
      },
      data: [
        [ 
          //data
        ],
      ]
    }],
  });
});
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir los datos de una serie y el javascript completo para reproducir exactamente la misma gráfica? A primera vista `chart` debería estar fuera de `series`.

Comment: Gracias por la edición, actualizo mi respuesta con la estructura correcta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La propiedad `chart` no debería ir dentro de la propiedad `series`, si no que debe ir en el primer nivel de la siguiente manera:

```js
let datos = [], num = 5000;
for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  datos.push(Math.cos(i / (num / 10)) * 9);
}
$(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('StockChart', {
    title: { style: { display : 'none' } },
    navigator: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      allButtonsEnabled: false,
      selected: 0,
      inputEnabled: false,
    },
    series: [{
      name: "...",
      data: datos,
    }],
    chart: {
      borderWidth: 1,
      plotBorderWidth: 1,
      spacingRight: 100, /* Ahora sí debería funcionar */
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="StockChart" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, a mi no me functiona esto tampoco.. He puesto el código entero en mi pregunta. Gracias!

Comment: Esto no te funciona porque no es literal. Actualizo la respuesta para contemplar la forma exacta en la que lo haces.

Comment: Prueba ahora con el código de mi edición

Comment: He estado haciendo pruebas y parece que si configuras el margen a cero el espacio no se establece. Prueba haciendo el cambio que te propongo y, además, eliminando la propiedad que configura el margen.

Comment: Gracias por las ediciones... Por alguna razón me sigue sin dar ningún espacio a la derecha... Voy a poner más información en mi pregunta, a ver si ayuda. He copiado el código de tu última edición propuesta...

Comment: ¿Quitaste el margen?

Comment: Resulta que el Spacing Right no funciona si tengo muchos datos... cuando pongo 10-20 datos tu código funciona perfecto, pero cuando utilizo 1400 datos, la gráfica ocupa todo el espacio... será mi error en CSS o un bug en Highcharts.. me quedará por descubrir. Gracias! :)

Comment: Claro, podría ser. Yo hice las pruebas en esta URL: https://jsfiddle.net/OscarGarcia/cbyo28qd/ podrás comprobar que allí funcionaba todo perfectamente, porque apenas tenía 12 datos. PD: Acabo de hacer pruebas con 3774 datos y sigue funcionando en mi ejemplo.

Comment: Acabo de modificar mi respuesta para convertirla en un ejemplo en línea. Puedes jugar con el ejemplo cambiando el número de elementos que se crean en `datos`. Por defecto se muestran 5000 valores, por lo que algo debe pasar en tu página para que no se use el espacio derecho con tantos elementos.